# VBA: paste named range to named cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range named "template" (in my example it's in the cells 'presets'!$a$25:$e$33 ) and I would like to copy this range into another named range "location_drop" (in my example it's in 'work'!$M$44)

When I do this:

```
Range("template").Copy Range("location_drop")
```

Nothing happens, I have a debug.print before and after this line and I see these 2 debugs, but nothing of that copy action.
Any idea what could be the problem ? Is it because my ranges have a different size ?

Comment: It should either work or cause an error. Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` statement in effect?

Comment: Please, try `Debug.print Range("template").Address(external:=True), Range("location_drop").Address(external:=True)`. What does it return in Immediate Window? Are there the ranges you think they should be?

Comment: Yes indeed... I had an error resume statement.
When I remove it I have an error "Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

Comment: @FaneDuru the error is coming from the Range("template").address(external:=true)  (I've split both debugs, the "location_drop" is correct). It's the same error as I had previously (Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed). The name of the range is 100% correct, so I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: Which is the name in discussion scope? Is it possible to be the sheet where it belongs to? If so, you should try `Sheets("Work").Range("template")`...

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. This code is located in the "onChange" Function from this particular sheet (the "work" sheet). So add the other sheets before the range made it work.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Just to add to what @FaneDuru said, in excel if you are declaring a range, I would recommend being in the habit of declaring the full name of the range or putting it into a variable to work with. This eliminates confusion between sheet-level and workbook-level ranges.